How to prove that the multiplication is not continuous in the $\sigma$-strong topology if the Hilbert space is infinite-diminsional
Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.
I understand that the multiplication is not continuous in the strong topology by finding a counterexample and showing $(A_\lambda, B_\lambda) \to (0,0)$ in the strong topology but $A_\lambda B_\lambda \not\to 0$.
However, for that example, I could not prove that $(A_\lambda, B_\lambda) \to 0$ in the $\sigma$-strong topology.
Can you show me any examples?

Let $H = \ell^2$, $S_1(H)_+$ be the space of positive trace-class operators, $\mathcal{P}_F(S_1(H)_+)$ be the collection of all finite subsets of $S_1(H)_+$. Let $\Lambda$ be the net with the underlying set $\mathcal{P}_F(S_1(H)_+) \times \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and with ordering defined by $(F_1, r_1) \leq (F_2, r_2)$ iff $F_1 \subset F_2$ and $r_1 \leq r_2$. For each $(F, r) \in \Lambda$, let $T_F = \sum_{t \in F} t$, which is a positive trace-class operator. Thus, by spectral theorem, there exists a nonzero orthogonal projection $P_{F, r}$ s.t. $\text{Tr}(P_{F, r}T_FP_{F, r}) < \frac{1}{r^3}$. Hence, for any $t \in F$, as $t \leq T_F$,
$$\begin{split}
|\text{Tr}(tP_{F, r})| &= \text{Tr}(P_{F, r}tP_{F, r})\\
&\leq \text{Tr}(P_{F, r}T_FP_{F, r})\\
&< \frac{1}{r^3}
\end{split}$$
Therefore, letting $A_{F, r} = rP_{F, r}$, we see that, for any $t \in S_1(H)_+$,
$$\lim_{(F, r) \in \Lambda} |\text{Tr}(tA_{F, r}^\ast A_{F, r})| = 0$$
i.e., $A_{F, r} \to 0$ in the $\sigma$-strong topology. Now, for each $(F, r) \in \Lambda$, since $P_{F, r}$ is nonzero, we may choose a unit vector $v_{F, r} \in P_{F, r}H$ and let,
$$E_{F, r} = |v_{F, r}\rangle\langle e_1|$$
Then let $B_{F, r} = \frac{1}{r}E_{F, r}$. Since $\|B_{F, r}\| = \frac{1}{r} \to 0$, we have $B_{F, r} \to 0$ in norm and thus also in the $\sigma$-strong topology. However, $A_{F, r}B_{F, r} = E_{F, r} \not\to 0$ in the $\sigma$-strong topology, as,
$$\|E_{F, r}e_1\| = \|v_{F, r}\| = 1$$
for all $(F, r) \in \Lambda$.

Thank you very much for the answer.
Since I am not very familiar with operator algebra, I have several questions.

What is the spectral theorem that leads to the existence of such $P_{F,r}$?
The definition of the $\sigma$-strong topology that I have learned is given by seminorms $A \mapsto (\sum_n |Ax_n|^2)^{1/2}$ where $\sum_n |x_n|^2 < \infty$. What is your definition of $\sigma$-strong topology and does it coincide with mine? Or, can you prove $A_{F,r} \to 0$ in my definition of $\sigma$-strong topology?

Thank you.

@Salangidae The spectral theorem I referred to is this one, namely, any self-adjoint compact operator can be unitarily diagonalized. Since $T_F$ is of trace-class, its nonzero eigenvalues are summable. So $P_{F, r}$ is just the projection off the first few eigenspaces.

For the second question, there are two equivalent definitions of the $\sigma$-strong topology, one of which is the one you wrote down. The other one, which I used, is the topology generated by seminorms $A\mapsto\text{Tr}(TA^\ast A)^{1/2}$ where $T$ is a positive trace-class operator. To go back and forth between the two definitions, note that if $(x_n)$ is as given in your definition, then $\sum_n |x_n\rangle\langle x_n|$ is positive of trace-class. The converse comes from the spectral theorem. Namely, if $T$ is positive of trace-class, then you can choose $x_n=\lambda_n^{1/2}v_n$, where…

… $\lambda_n$ is the $n$-th nonzero eigenvalue of $T$ and $v_n$ is the associated unit eigenvector. (The point of using this definition, instead of your definition, is that I need to go from $(x_n)$ being not necessarily orthogonal to an orthogonal sequence, which is a direct consequence of the spectral theorem in the formulation using trace-class operators.)
